# In http2, if the client ignores the server's settings frame, what should the server do?

Tags: http2

When there are many connections, we want to reduce the dynamic table size through `SETTINGS_HEADER_TABLE_SIZE` in settings frame. If the client ignores the settings frame, and does not send a settings frame with an *ack flag*, will the server use the default value (4096 octets)?If so, the client can send many requests with a 4096 octets dynamic table after receiving a server settings frame. This may cause the server's memory used too much.How to avoid this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client [*must*](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#rfc.section.6.5) apply the settings with promptness and send a Settings Ack back, this is not optional. Any other behavior from the client is non-compliant and in those situations the server can close the connection. For the specific case where the client lingers for too long without acknowledging the Setting, the server can close the  connection using a GoAway frame with reason SETTINGS_TIMEOUT.

The other thing is that the HPACK dynamic table is "global" for the HTTP/2 connection. So, the only way that an attacker can really abuse the default size is by opening many different connections, not by making many requests on the same connection. In my opinion, you always want to limit the number of connections that can come from a single IP address, otherwise attackers won't even need a botnet to perform a DDOS attack on your server.

Reducing the size of the dynamic table under 4096 bytes could increase headers traffic and maybe be counter-productive for performance.

Comment: Really thank you! It's my fault. I didn't pay attention to the SETTINGS_TIMEOUT. Your advice is really helpful.

Comment: In fact, I just want to make a test on my server to check which is the bottleneck, memory or CPU, when there are many connections and there are many requests(stream) on every connection. My server is NGINX-1.9.7, however it doesn't implement settings ack logic. Now I need to implement it, and make a directive to set the dynamic table size, instead of only using the default value.

Comment: You could use the tool [h2spec](https://github.com/summerwind/h2spec) from Moto Ishizawa to check the extent of  NginX HTTP/2 implementation. You can also give a try to [Shimmercat](https://www.shimmercat.com/), and if you have any issues there I will work with you on them. How are you planning to generate load for your setup? Did you configured http/2 in JMeter?

Comment: Really nice! I didn't configured http/2 in JMeter, and I need to have a deep understanding of it. Many thanks for your advice and kindness.